# Changing a single tick mark on jqPlot

Tags: javascript, jqplot

When graphing something in `jqPlot`, there's always a negative number (even though the data is never negative), which is fine because it makes the chart have more padding and is better visible.

Anyway, my question is when the data is in the very low numbers, `jqPlot` shows the negative tick mark as -.2 for example. Is it possible to set it to an even number such as -.5?

Basically, **I just want to change a tick number manually to something desired. Is this possible?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it goes to a manual changing of a tick and setting of other options, for example, as @maliayas suggests playing with min/max, doesn't help you could always grab the wanted tick using `jQuery`.

For an example showing how to [change a tick manually using jQuery please see this sample.](http://jsfiddle.net/Boro/AqKZz/)

Comment: You can also predefine tick values: http://jsfiddle.net/mali/er6Eq/ (forked from Boro's code)

Answer (score 2):

You can play with the min and max values of the ticks on axes. Here is the code:

```
var plot = $.jqplot('graph', [dataSet], {
    // ...
    axes : {
        xaxis : {
            min : 'X',
            max : 'X',
            // ...
        },
        yaxis : {
            min : 'X',
            max : 'X',
            // ...
        }
    },
    // ...
});
```

Hope this helps.